# Scala project MySQL connection errors

Tags: mysql, scala, mysql-connector

I'm trying to make my scala project connect to a mysql database (which I've spun up with MAMP) and keep getting this error. Any chance someone could help diagnose it? Thanks in advance!

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="healthcenters">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>healthcenterdataload.DataToStoreClass</class>
        <class>healthcenterdataload.HealthCenterData</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/healthcenters"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here's the bit where the storing is attempting to occur:

```
      val con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/healthcenters?profileSQL=true")

      em.persist(dataToStore)
      con.commit()
      con.close()
```

And here's the giant error output:

```
    scala> import healthcenterdataload._
import healthcenterdataload._

scala> val url = "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/8nqg-ia7v.json"
url: String = https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/8nqg-ia7v.json

scala> DataToStore.storeData(url)
May 16, 2017 11:41:41 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: healthcenters
        ...]
May 16, 2017 11:41:41 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
May 16, 2017 11:41:41 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
May 16, 2017 11:41:41 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
May 16, 2017 11:41:41 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
May 16, 2017 11:41:41 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/healthcenters]
May 16, 2017 11:41:41 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
May 16, 2017 11:41:41 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
May 16, 2017 11:41:41 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
        at healthcenterdataload.Model$.emf(Model.scala:11)
        at healthcenterdataload.Model$.em(Model.scala:13)
        at healthcenterdataload.DataToStore$.$anonfun$storeData$1(HealthCenter.scala:46)
        at healthcenterdataload.DataToStore$.$anonfun$storeData$1$adapted(HealthCenter.scala:44)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
        at healthcenterdataload.DataToStore$.storeData(HealthCenter.scala:44)
        at $line5.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:16)
        at $line5.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line5.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line5.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line5.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:993)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:566)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:32)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:30)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:33)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:565)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:592)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:562)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:830)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:698)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:416)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:437)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.$anonfun$process$1(ILoop.scala:1012)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(ILoop.scala:1023)
        at xsbt.ConsoleInterface.run(ConsoleInterface.scala:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:107)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.console(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
        at sbt.Console.sbt$Console$$console0$1(Console.scala:22)
        at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Console.scala:23)
        at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Console.scala:23)
        at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Console.scala:23)
        at sbt.Logger$$anon$4.apply(Logger.scala:84)
        at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:248)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
        ... 58 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
        at healthcenterdataload.Model$.emf(Model.scala:11)
        at healthcenterdataload.Model$.em(Model.scala:13)
        at healthcenterdataload.DataToStore$.$anonfun$storeData$1(HealthCenter.scala:46)
        at healthcenterdataload.DataToStore$.$anonfun$storeData$1$adapted(HealthCenter.scala:44)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
        at healthcenterdataload.DataToStore$.storeData(HealthCenter.scala:44)
        at $line5.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:16)
        at $line5.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line5.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line5.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line5.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:993)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:566)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:32)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:30)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:33)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:565)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:592)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:562)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:830)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:698)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:416)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:437)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.$anonfun$process$1(ILoop.scala:1012)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(ILoop.scala:1023)
        at xsbt.ConsoleInterface.run(ConsoleInterface.scala:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:107)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.console(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
        at sbt.Console.sbt$Console$$console0$1(Console.scala:22)
        at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Console.scala:23)
        at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Console.scala:23)
        at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Console.scala:23)
        at sbt.Logger$$anon$4.apply(Logger.scala:84)
        at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:248)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2847)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
        ... 73 more
```